# Is Redux required for storing user session like is user logged details?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I've been working with react from past 1.5 years. When I came across redux it's good library for state management of an app but when it comes to local storage I think it's good to store user session because redux store will change because of page refresh. So I'm little bit confused what to do with redux also it's little complex writing code. Can somebody help me which is better to use for storing user session? Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of Redux (or any other state management tool for SPAs) is to help you manage your app's state when the app is loaded in the browser. You can't "keep it" after you close the app. Use JWT or cookies for storing info about user sessions in the browser.

Also, you don't have to use Redux for your state management if you find it too complex. React's Context Api may be sufficient. But again, not for storing user sessions.